# Ruby on rails multiplication acting weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I do:

```
params[:page] * 10
```

It gives me 1111111111.
I want it to return 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `params[:page].to_i * 10`  (for the record: `nil.to_i #=> 0`)

Comment: Why didn't you just say that in an answer so the OP could accept it?

Answer (score 3):

String multiplication will repeat the string n times. `params` is **always** an array of strings in Rails, so you need to convert `params[:page]` to an integer first with `to_i`.